# Sharing wifi connection through Ethernet

Tags: networking

I'd like to share the wifi connection I have on my raspberry pi through wifi with a separate wifi router. Is this possible with Rasbian?

Comment: It's going to depend very much on what wi-fi dongle you are using and whether it supports access-point mode.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check previous SE answer on the topic of internet sharing:

[Internet Connection Sharing](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13941/internet-connection-sharing?rq=1)

Or the following article:

http://blog.chaucery.com/2013/02/raspberry-pi-wireless-bridge.html

If you google around you will find multiple articles explaining how you can share either Wifi or the Ethernet connection with other devices...